# Difference matrix for large vector R

Tags: r, matrix

I've got a large vector (length: 250k) and want to calculate the difference of each element to all others.

One way I've done it on a smaller size is this:

```
n = 1000
set.seed(35)
values = sample(1:1e3, n, replace=T)
mat_temp = matrix(values, n, n, byrow=TRUE) - matrix(values, n, n, byrow=FALSE)
mat_temp = abs(mat_temp)
```

It's not ideal because I'd only need the lower part of the diagonal (or absolute differences).

And the main issue: how can I efficiently run it for the full 250k*250k (`n = 250000`) matrix? With a 16GB RAM, is that possible at all? Tried `bigmemory` but it fails to initialise the big matrix.

Is there a way (I only need the differences)?

Comment: You do realize that 250k^2 is 62.5 billion elements, right. Even if you only want the lower part, that's twice as much bytes as you have

Comment: Yes, is there any other way to do it? I'm aware a 250^2 matrix is not gonna happen.

Comment: For which algorithm do you need all of those elements to exist in memory at once (as opposed to an ability to compute them on the fly as needed)?

Comment: To expand on my last comment, from an algorithmic point of view, there is very little difference between `M[i,j]` and `abs(values[i] - values[j])`. I don't see much gain in trying to pre-compute all those differences rather than calculating them as needed.